# navigation drawer google maps v2 , map blocking drawer

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, navigation-drawer

I have this problem when opening drawer on gingerbread and behind is google map v2. Map that should be on screen behind gets on top of everything.

Now I could bypass this by hiding map when drawer opens and show it when closes but I'm looking for more elegant solution if someone came up with any?

[image: Map overlaying navigation drawer]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug with google maps api v2 and black space. Maybe you have got similar problem. For solutions look here:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/228
and here:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/168

As far as I remember solutions are one of this:

- extending Google Maps and make it to redraw every view more often
- set map's z index on top param to true
- put transparent overlay over Google Maps view

Answer (score 13):

Just wrap SupportMapFragment with FrameLayout and put transparent View above like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Map fragment -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        <!-- Transparent view -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Tested with Android 4.0.4 - works fine for me

Comment: In my case - adding transparent view to existing layout, right after a map's frament, worked like a charm.
Just for history's sake - this ORIGINALLY worked ok in HTC Desire X 4.1.1, but failed on Sony 4.0.0 and HTC Desire SV 4.0.1. Now - works everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I have got the same problem here on ICS 4.0.4. The solutions mentioned in jfeinstein10's github post seems not working for me. But I have found a workaround, even it is not the best.

When creating DrawerToggle object I override this event

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
{
     super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
     mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
     mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
     mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

bringChildToFront and requestLayout method should overcome the drawer rendering problem while setScrimColor will get rid of the shadow. Too bad that I haven't found a workaround to render the shadow correctly as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You should override the onDrawerSlide function and move the  drawer to front

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    DrawerLayout  Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
                    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
                        {
                            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                            Drawer.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
                            Drawer.requestLayout();
                            Drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        }
                    };
```