# NavigationDrawer behind MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer, mapfragment

[SOLVED] I added this to MainActivity XML file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/place_map_here"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bugfixview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

and where I changed the fragments:

```
mapFragment = new FragmentMapView();
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.place_map_here, mapFragment, "map");
ft.commit();
```

Edit: Just realized that I do not use the MapFragment xml file.(older build did sorry)

I´ve changed my Fragment to a MapFragment and now my NavigationDrawer slides in behind the MapFragment :(
Code:

MapFragmant xml ( removed code)

MainActivity xml. Here is my drawer declared

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#333"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this is the information you need to be awesome like always and help noobs like me :)

Comment: What happens if you change the layout so the root is `DrawerLayout` and not `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Could you post java code ,I want to see how you are replacing the fragment.

Comment: Can you put the `MapView` inside `main` ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432961/slidingdrawer-over-googlemap/16231935#16231935

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733723/navigation-drawer-google-maps-v2-map-blocking-drawer

Comment: @gunar Nothing happend when I changed it to DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hack it might help you, just change your layout to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!-- hack to fix ugly black Background with maps v2 -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

DrawerLayout needs to be the root of your layout, so try deleting the RelativeLayout.  I assume you are attaching your MapFragment to the FrameLayout, main.

Also, what api version are you on?  I've noticed some weird graphics bugs on api<10 including black borders and black flashing backgrounds with both map fragments and drawers.

Answer (score 0):

we can solve NavigationDrawer going behind MapFragment by using view just below map fragment in the layout.

eg -

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"      
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```